# Java multithreading, getting threads to work in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose you need to deal with 2 threads, a `Reader` and a `Processor`.

`Reader` will read a portion of the stream data and will pass it to the `Processor`, that will do something.

The idea is to not stress the Reader with too much of data.

In the set up, i

```
// Processor will pick up data from pipeIn and will place the output in pipeOut
Thread p = new Thread(new Processor(pipeIn, pipeOut));
p.start();

// Reader will pick a bunch of bits from the InputStream and place it to pipeIn
Thread r = new Thread(new Reader(inputStream, pipeIn));
r.start();
```

Needless to say, neither pipe is null, when initialized.

I am thinking ... When `Processor` has been started it attempts to read from the pipeIn, in the following loop:

```
    while (readingShouldContinue) {
        Thread.sleep(1); // To avoid tight loop

        byte[] justRead = readFrom.getDataCurrentlyInQueue();
        writeDataToPipe(processData(justRead));
    }
```

If there is no data to write, it will write nothing, should be no problem.

The `Reader` comes alive and picks up some data from a stream:

```
    while ((in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        // Writes to what processor considers a pipeIn
        writeTo.addDataToQueue(buffer); 
    }
```

In Pipe itself, i synchronize access to data.

```
public byte[] getDataCurrentlyInQueue() {

    synchronized (q) {
        byte[] a = q.peek();
        q.clear();
        return a;
    }
}
```

I expect the 2 threads to run semi in parallel, interchanging activities between `Reader` and a `Processor`. What happens however is that

- Reader reads all blocks up front
- Processor treats everything as 1 single block

**What am i missing please?**

Comment: InputStream.read(byte[]) is a blocking call

Comment: @guido Hi guido. Is there something you can recommend i do?

Comment: try looking at java.nio SocketChannel and ByteBuffer classes: AH and Pipe class ;)

Comment: @JAM: *(not an answer)*  What is this *"Thread.sleep(1); // To avoid tight loop"*?  Are you concerned about what is called busy-looping/busy-waiting?  You should simply use a *BlockingQueue* and calls its *take* method.  Also, you won't need to synchronize yourself on the queue.  Use higher-level concurrency facilities.  In this case a BlockingQueue is what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reinvented parts of the java concurrent library. it would make things a lot easier if you modeled your threads with `BlockingQueue` instead of synchronizind things yourself.

Basically your producer would put chunks on the `BlockingQueue` und your consumer would while(true) loop over the queue and call get(). That way the producer would block/wait until there is a new chunk on the queue.

Answer (score 2):

> What am i missing please?

(First I should point out that you've left out some critical bits of the code and other information that is needed for a specific fact-based answer.)

I can think of a number of possible explanations:

- There may simply be a bug in your application.  There's not a lot of point guessing what that bug might be, but if you showed us more code ...
- The OS thread scheduler will tend to let an active thread keep running until it blocks.  If your processor has only one core (or if the OS only allows your application to use one core), then the second thread may starve ... long enough for the first one to finish.
- Even if you have multiple cores, the OS thread scheduler *may* be slow to assign extra cores, especially if the 2nd thread starts and then immediately blocks.
- It is possible that there is some "granularity" effect in the buffering that is causing work not to appear in the queue.  (You could view this as a bug ... or as a tuning issue.)
- It could simply be that you are not giving the application enough load for multi-threading to kick in.

Finally, I can't figure out the `Thread.sleep` stuff either.  A properly written multi-threaded application does not use `Thread.sleep` for anything but long term delays; e.g. threads that do periodic house-keeping tasks in the background.  If you use `sleep` instead of blocking, then 1) you risk making the application non-responsive, and 2) you *may* encourage the OS thread scheduler to give the thread fewer time slices.  It could well be that this is the source of your trouble *vis-a-vis* thread starvation.

Answer (score 0):

The reader is reading everything before its first time-slice. This means that the reading is finishing before the processor ever gets a chance to run.

Try increasing the amount of bytes that are being read, or slow down the reader somehow; maybe with a sleep() call every once in a while.

Btw. Don't poll. It is a horrendous waste of CPU cycles, and it doesn't scale at all.
Also use a synchronized queue and forget the manual locking. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html

Answer (score 0):

When using multiple threads you need to determine whether you

- have work which can be performed in parallel efficiently.
- are not adding more overhead than the improvement you are likely to achieve
- the OS, or some library is not already optimised to do what you are trying to do.

In your case, you have a good example of when not to use multi-threads.  The OS is already tuned to read ahead and buffer data before you ask for it.  The work the Reader does is relatively trivial.  The overhead of creating new buffers, adding them to a queue and passing the data between threads is likely to be greater than the amount of work you are performing in parallel.

When you try to use multiple threads to do a task best done by a single thread, you will get strange profiling/tuning results.

+1 For a good question.